# Using the combined Build/Cesium.js instead of the individual .js files

Tags: javascript, dojo, cesiumjs

I've been going around in circles trying to get the [Cesium](http://cesium.agi.com/) dependencies not to import when they're imported from the "[combined](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/Quick-Start)" `Cesium.js`.

I've got this code to a stage where it's correctly finding the path of Cesium files, but it is loading up 100's of them, instead of only the combined `Build/Cesium.js` and the `CesiumViewerWidget` (which doesn't seem to be included in combined). e.g. One of the many files it loads is `Source/Core/Clock.js` which is built into `Build/Cesium.js`.

How can I tell dojo or `CesiumViewerWidget` to assume the core dependencies are already there?

I'm running this with Rails, hence the `/assets/` path.

The code I'm working with:

```
<script src="/assets/cesium/Build/Cesium.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

require({
    baseUrl: '/assets/cesium/Source/Widgets',
    packages: [
        // {name: 'Cesium', location: '../../Build/Cesium'},
        {name: 'Widgets/Dojo/CesiumViewerWidget'},
        // {name: 'dojo/on', location: 'dojo/on'},
        // {name: 'dojo/dom', location: 'dojo/dom'},
        // {name: 'dojo/io-query', location: 'dojo/io-query'}
    ]},
    [
        'Widgets/Dojo/CesiumViewerWidget',
        'dojo/on', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/io-query'
    ], function(CesiumViewerWidget, on, dom, ioQuery) {
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After asking on the cesium-dev mailing list, I got an [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/rDdNTHWjY0s).

Basically, the combined `Cesium.js` is not meant to work with the dojo `require()` dependencies. It is a matter of removing the dependencies and using the global `Cesium` object that is available when including the combined `Cesium.js` file.